# How long will my Mobile Analyzer scans be available in the database if I don’t delete them?

Tags: virus-scanning

When I am running scans using the AppScan Mobile Analyzer SaaS offering, how long will my scans be stored in the database if I do not delete them?

Answer (score 0):

Scans will be held in the database for one year if the user does not manually delete them.